# how to render sidekiq/web UI in rails application layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm using rails 6 and sidekiq, I have: `require 'sidekiq/web'` and `mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'` in my routes.
I have `link_to sidekiq_web_path, target: :_blank` in application.html.erb.
It is working, but I want to render sidekiq dashboard view in application layout rather than redirect to it's page.
I was wondering if there any way to render it or override it's views and controller (something like this we can do with devise) ?

Comment: The easiest solution might be an IFRAME. You cannot render a Sidekiq view within your application layout, it just won't work.

Comment: thank you, it's good enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you [Mike Perham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1494519/mike-perham), Iframe is good enough!
Like this:

```
      <iframe src="/sidekiq" style="width: 100%; height: 90%"></iframe>
```